# RStudio not starting with Error code 10053

Tags: rstudio

Recently I have problems to open RStudio (version RStudio 2023.03.1+446 "Cherry Blossom " (6e31ffc3, 2023-05-09) for windows). Already tried to reinstall R as well as RStudio (R works fine) and open via command line, nothing helped. Here is the error message attached:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.03.1+446 "Cherry Blossom " (6e31ffc3, 2023-05-09) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.1+446 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/ingoa/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-ingoa.log*

```
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\os-builds\open-source-pipeline\rel-cherry-blossom\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\os-builds\open-source-pipeline\rel-cherry-blossom\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
2023-05-03T21:38:35.385899Z [rsession-ingoa] ERROR system error 10053 (Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\os-builds\open-source-pipeline\rel-cherry-blossom\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\os-builds\open-source-pipeline\rel-cherry-blossom\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
```

Reinstalled both R as well as RStudio, changed Internetconnection, tried to start via command terminal (Windows 11, 64 bit version)